# Sort records by date in shell using standard UNIX utilities sed, awk, sort, etc

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have two text files, `records` and `dates`:

`records`

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

`dates`

```
Fri Jul 15 23:20:01
Thu Jul 14 12:03:53
Mon Jul 10 10:11:35
Mon Jul 10 10:11:20
Mon Jul 10 10:11:15
```

Each line in `records` **matches** a line in `dates`. Both files are also **always sorted** chronologically.

I would like to display the following:

```
Fri Jul 15
  a

Thu Jul 14
  b

Mon Jul 10
  c
  d
  e
```

I can imagine a simple algorithm that loops through each line in `records` and compares the corresponding date in `dates` with the *last* date I checked, but this would be involved and I would like to know if it can be accomplished in a pipeline using `awk`, `sed`, `sort`, etc., **without** bashisms.

Comment: Perl is among the tools best suited to this task. Part of the motivation for designing Perl was the difficulty of handling multiple files simultaneously with AWK.

Comment: @msw I thought `Perl` was first, but now I see it was only created in 1987, whereas `awk` in 1977.

Comment: @msw that is ridiculous, awk has no problem handling multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: Forgive me, @EdMorton I should have said "awk of the time".

Comment: @msw no problem but awk at any time had no problem handling multiple files simultaneously, that was just never an issue. As I understand perl it does text manipulation like awk does but additionally does all the stuff that shell does. So if you want a tool to just do text manipulation you can use either awk or perl but if you want to do anything additional (e.g. manipulate processes) then your choice is awk+OS (shell if you're on UNIX) or perl. I don't know why perl was really invented though, unless maybe for portability across OSs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    sub(/ [0-9:]+$/,"")
    dates[NR] = $0
    next
}
{
    curr = dates[FNR]
    if (curr != prev) {
        print curr
    }
    print "  " $0
    prev = curr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk dates records
Fri Jul 15
  a
Thu Jul 14
  b
Mon Jul 10
  c
  d
  e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
paste -d:  <(awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' dates) records | awk -F: '$1!=prev{print $1"\n\t"$2;prev=$1;next} $1==prev{print "\t"$2}'
Fri Jul 15
    a
Thu Jul 14
    b
Mon Jul 10
    c
    d
    e
```

Explanation:

`<([command])` : Allows us to use the output of `[command]` as a file

`paste -d: <([awk] dates) records` : will paste output of the awk command with the records file using `:` as separator ex: `Fri Jul 15:a`

And the last awk command:

```
awk -F: '
         # If we have not seen date print date,new line,tab and record
         $1!=prev {print $1"\n\t"$2;prev=$1;next} 

         #if we have seen date print tab and record
         $1==prev{print "\t"$2}
        '
```

---

As Ed Morton pointed out in the comments, last awk command can be shorter:

```
awk  -F: '{print ($1==prev ? "" : $1"\n") "\t"$2; prev=$1}'
```

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but … I've not ploughed my way through the `awk` script because it is hidden off the screen.  There's no need for making everything a one-liner; you could perfectly well have a newline after the pipe symbol so your code is instantly readable. Indeed, 'one-liner' should be a term of abuse. That's presentational, though. More substantively, you're using 3 programs (`awk` twice and `paste` once) where one is sufficient. And you have not explained your answer in the slightest (an accusation that could be levelled against the accepted answer too, but it is laid out legibly).

Comment: I didn't down-vote it either but it is an unnecessarily complicated collection of separate tool invocations, pipelines, and bashisms (which the OP specifically said he didn't want) so it would not be a reasonable approach to a solution. And yes, cramming scripts all onto a single line adds zero value. Newlines are surprisingly cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. @EdMorton, the only complicated part is the last `awk` command which I am sure you master `:)`

Comment: @Tiago no, that last awk command is trivial (but has some redundancy making it longer than necessary), it's figuring out what the combination of all of the tools and pipes and that `<(..)` bashism are doing that is complicated. If you hadn't posted the output I wouldn't have had a clue what it does.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I edited my answer explaining what it does.

Comment: I can't use bashisms because I am using fish, which has no builtin string manipulation support like useful-but-quirky bash.

Comment: @JorgeBucaran IMO you shouldn't use the tag `bash` then. there is a tag for `fish`

Comment: @Tiago I know, but I didn't want an answer tied to any shell (hence the title of the question). I may need to switch to bash or zsh later.

Comment: @JorgeBucaran: if you have specific shells in mind, use the generic [tag:shell] tag and specify such constraints (and maybe add the tags for specific shells too).  The constraints aren't unreasonable if they're stated.

Comment: You never need to write `cond{action1;next} !cond{action2}`, writing `cond{action1;next} {action2}` is sufficient so you can remove your test on `$1==prev`. I think (but haven't tested it) that the whole last awk script could be written with less redundancy as `awk '{print ($1==prev ? "" : $1"\n") "\t"$2; prev=$1}'`

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I tested and it works. I've gotta get used to ternary.